# Make textures low-res

Tags: rendering, texturing

I want to make a ps1 style render of a companion cube I made recently for another project but the problem is that the companion cube I originally made was textured with substance painter and that the textures are high quality, which is not what I want if I want it to look old.

Comment: "old" is a very relative term can you edit your question and attach an example image of what you have and an example of what you refer to as "old"

Comment: @RickT here, sorry for the bad clarification.
[old](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ficdn2.digitaltrends.com%2Fimage%2Fcrash-bandicoot-500x500.jpg&f=1&nofb=1)
[new](https://i.ibb.co/7v9GwyL/image.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your textures are baked to image files, you could just resize them. There is the option for this in Blenders texture painting tab. This is assuming you're after a pixelate effect.